# Unclear about postfix and hostname in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, postfix, mail-server

I need to preface this by saying I am in no means an expert with linux or servers. I have a digitalocean droplet that I am using as a webserver for a couple of domains.  I am looking to implement a simple mailserver to use with the domains.  I want to be able to use all of the domains with the mailserver.  I have been going over the following article [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin).

In all of the tutorials I see they say to change the hostname to the main fqdn like so `mail.yourdomain.com`.  But in the tutorial I referenced above it is configured to use virtual domains to refer to. So do I really need to change the hostname to a fqdn in this instance?  My current hostname is `vm1.webserver` which is obviously not a domain name.  But as you all know domains come and go so I don't really want to change the hostname to a domain that I may not even use in the future.

So what do I need to modify in the tutorial to get the mailserver to work with multiple domains like example1.com and example2.net so I can have mail for both domains.

What is the relationship with the hostname and postfix when configured to use virtual domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship is that many anti-spam methods check both the forward and reverse DNS entry.  In other words, they check that there is an `A` record for the hostname advertised in the postfix greeting; that the IP it resolves to is the IP address that the postfix connection is coming from; and that the reverse DNS (rDNS or PTR) entry for the mail server's IP matches the hostname advertised in the postfix greeting.

It does not matter that you are using virtual mailboxes, nor does it particularly matter which domain you choose.  The key is that the hostname configured in postfix should have an `A` record in your DNS and the reverse DNS for the VPS's IP.

Of course, you should also configure SPF records in the DNS stating that each domain is authorized to send mail from that IP, but that's not directly related to the choice of hostname.

Comment: Ok so should I just pick a domain to use as a main domain and set that as my fqdn and the hostname?  And then that should work for all domains on the server.

Comment: Yes.  Pick one.  Make sure it has an `A` record pointing to the VPS IP.  Make sure the reverse DNS of the IP is set to whatever you pick.  Set SPF records for all domains on the server.

Comment: Ok one more thing should I make it something like mail.mydomain.com and then set up an A record for that or should I just use the main domain like mydomain.com?

Comment: It would be better practice to use `mail.mydomain.com` or `smtp.mydomain.com` etc. but there is no 'rule' and you can always change it later.